# package configuration issue

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, package-management

Looking for pointers on a package configuration issue. This is a stripped down version of Debian 8 (ReadyNAS 6.10.3 running on a Netgear RN202 NAS).

I think the problem may have been triggered by installing the third-party RNXtras PHP7.2 app that upgrades the default PHP from 5.6 to 7.2. The combination worked fine when I first installed it a while back. But ReadyNAS (Debian) was upgraded on the box since then, and after doing a recent full wipe / install of ReadyNAS then reinstall of RNXtras PHP7.2, things went south: Both an uninstall *and* install of RNXtras PHP7.2 is failing now - as are other installs.

The primary symptom right now is this sort of thing:

```
# apt-get install git
...
insserv: warning: script 'K01ddclient' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Service nfs-common has to be enabled to start service nfs-kernel-server
insserv: Service rpcbind has to be enabled to start service nfs-kernel-server
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

# apt-cache policy nfs-kernel-server
nfs-kernel-server:
  Installed: 1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1
  Candidate: 1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main armel Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.2.8-9 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian jessie/main armel Packages

# apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: 1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1
  Candidate: 1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1 500
        500 https://repos.rnxtras.com/debian/rnx-rnos6 rnx-rnos6/main armel Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u10 500
        500 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main armel Packages
     1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u6 500
        500 http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian jessie/main armel Packages
```

Also, similar errors for "apt-get remove", etc.

Perhaps this could be solved through package pinning, but not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think I fixed it by commenting out the left-over repository from the third-party RNXtras PHP7.2 app (which I had tried, unsuccessfully, to uninstall), then purging and reinstalling a few things:

```
# vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rnxtras.list
# deb https://repos.rnxtras.com/debian/rnx-rnos6 rnx-rnos6 main

# apt-get update

# apt-get remove --purge rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server

# apt-get install rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server

# apt-get remove --purge git-man git

# apt-get install git
```

If anyone sees any issues with this approach, let me know.